# Uploading release asset to Github is corrupting file

Tags: python-requests, github-api

I am trying to automate our Github release process, and as part of it I am uploading release artifacts to Github release. Artifact I am uploading is a `tar.gz` file. I am using following python3.7 code to upload the artifact:

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
   response = self._request_session.post(endpoint,
                                         params={'name': local_artifact.filename},
                                         files={local_artifact.filename: file})
```

Response status code I am getting is 201, which is expected as per Github [upload release asset api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset) documentation.

However, when I am downloading artifacts from Github, I am neither able to validate sha256 of the file, nor I am able open the tarball. On running `tar -zxvf test.tar.gz` I am getting following error:

```
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I have already tested the file on local which I am uploading and that is working fine.

Can anyone please help me in identifying the problem here?

Here is response text I get after uploading file:

```
{
   "url":"https://api.github.com/repos/c2tarun/upload_test_repo/releases/assets/17244134",
   "id":17244134,
   "node_id":"MDEyOlJlbGVhc2VBc3NldDE3MjQ0MTM0",
   "name":"test.tar.gz",
   "label":"",
   "uploader":{
      "login":"c2tarun",
      "id":1129670,
      ...truncating for readability.
      "type":"User",
      "site_admin":false
   },
   "content_type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=1a13638ee5f5f57d303508eea4e64211",
   "state":"uploaded",
   "size":11969682,
   "download_count":0,
   "created_at":"2020-01-09T23:49:54Z",
   "updated_at":"2020-01-09T23:50:18Z",
   "browser_download_url":"https://github.com/c2tarun/upload_test_repo/releases/download/untagged-1baa5c7dd7f5a8d506cc/test.tar.gz"
}
```

Interesting update: Uploading same file multiple times, gives me different sha on downloading.

More Update: I thought that may be I am providing wrong `Content-Type` header for `tar.gz` file, so I created a zip file and used `Content-Type` as `application/zip`. I am still seeing same issue. Here are my request headers for zip file:

```
{
   'User-Agent':'python-requests/2.22.0',
   'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
   'Accept':'*/*',
   'Connection':'keep-alive',
   'Content-Type':'application/zip',
   'Content-Length':'332',
   'Authorization':'Basic xxxxxxxxx'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sort of found the solution, following code works:
with open(local_artifact.path, 'rb') as file:
                response = self._request_session.post(endpoint, params={'name': name}, data=file, headers=headers)

with content-type as application/zip.

Not posting this as an answer because I am not sure why this works.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the Content-Type is 'application/tar+gzip' or debug with

```
file --mime-type -b test.tar.gz
```

command.